# Creating domain name checker

Tags: c#, asp.net, dns

I wonder how to make a domain name checker (testing for availability) for top-level domains?

Eg. to check if the domain: stackoverflow.com or stackoverflow.dk is available or not.

Do I need to be subscribed to a service to do this, or is there some simple magic behind such test?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do a [WHOIS](http://www.whois.net/) lookup - see http://www.aspdev.org/articles/build-whois-lookup-asp.net/

Comment: WHOIS the correct answer, but You have to be online to check.

Comment: @ckuetbach how could you possibly check domain name availability without being online?

Comment: I can't. But I wanted to make this clear. But you are right, it is obvious, that you have to be online to check the domain.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a protocol for this check ["A Domain Availability Check"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5144). I am not sure if this is only for the german .de domains or for all domains. Maybe this will help you a  little bit.

Comment: The protocol is for all domains, but most TLDs do not have a server that is actually running this service, and the one server I found via google which offers it was only for .de and was very unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to create a `webRequest` object to fire off a whois request.  You can then parse the results from the HTML using regex.  I've done this on a number of occasions and it works well (providing the underlying website doesn't change)

Answer (score 0):

an helpfullweb service client 
http://www.whoislookup.be/wswhois/wswhois.asmx

referance

http://www.whoislookup.be/using-an-webservice-to-access-whois-search.aspx